# Python adding config files to path

Tags: python

I have directory structure like following:

```
           analytics  
       /   /     \   \
    conf script  src  other  
    /  \  /  \   /  \   
   <setup>         <source>  

< setup >:  
       setup.yaml  
       sql.yaml  

< source  >:  
       src/  
           folder A/  
                    s1.py  
                    s2.py  
                    ...  
           folder B/
                    m1.py  
                    m2.py  
                    ...
```

How can I inclue the setup files in  of this structure to the source files in  structure without hardcoding the paths

I tried sys.path.append('< path >') but when I try to open the file I see error

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/Users/user/Documents/work/dw/analytics/conf')
>>> f = open('setup.yaml', 'r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'setup.yaml'
>>> f = open('setup.yaml', 'r')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`open()` (and all the other file access functions) don't care about `sys.path`. It's only used when importing modules.

Create your own variable that contains the path that contains your files, and use it.